# Looping animations in "React Native Reanimated 2" sync after a while

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I was using the reanimated v2 for creating animations for an app. I was creating a splash (loading) screen with three dots that jump up and down. The 3 dots are supposed to have certain **constant** **delay** (**interval**) between them. Like the animation when the other person is typing in facebook's messenger.

The animation looks fine in the beginning but after a while the 2 dots or even 3 dots depending on the delays and duration **sync** **up** and I am left with 2 or 3 dots absolutely in sync with each other. Here is the video of the problem [animation video](https://youtu.be/9RJQ1F24n3E)

I am very new to react-native and reanimated. So I am assuming the problem is in my code. I have no idea if this is the correct way to do this. The code examples I see in reanimated v1 have "***startClock***" and custom "***runTiming***" functions but I couldn't find them in the docs for v2. [reanimated docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/nodes/startClock/#startclock)

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Animated, {
  useSharedValue,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  withRepeat,
  withTiming,
  withDelay,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import { themeColor } from "../../assets/ThemeColor";

const Loading = () => {
  const y1 = useSharedValue(0);
  const y2 = useSharedValue(0);
  const y3 = useSharedValue(0);

  const animatedStyles1 = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [
        {
          translateY: withDelay(
            0,
            withRepeat(withTiming(y1.value, { duration: 200 }), -1, true)
          ),
        },
      ],
    };
  });
  const animatedStyles2 = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [
        {
          translateY: withDelay(
            100,
            withRepeat(withTiming(y2.value, { duration: 200 }), -1, true)
          ),
        },
      ],
    };
  });
  const animatedStyles3 = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [
        {
          translateY: withDelay(
            200,
            withRepeat(withTiming(y3.value, { duration: 200 }), -1, true)
          ),
        },
      ],
    };
  });

  /**
   *
   *
   *
   *
   */

  useEffect(() => {
    y1.value = -10;
    y2.value = -10;
    y3.value = -10;
  }, []);

  /**
   *
   *
   *
   *
   *
   */

  return (
    <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[styles.ballStyle, animatedStyles1]}
      ></Animated.View>
      <Animated.View
        style={[styles.ballStyle, animatedStyles2]}
      ></Animated.View>
      <Animated.View
        style={[styles.ballStyle, animatedStyles3]}
      ></Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  loadingContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },

  ballStyle: {
    width: 13,
    height: 13,
    backgroundColor: themeColor,
    borderRadius: 13,
    margin: 10,
  },
});

export default Loading;
```

**Can someone please tell me why the animations sync up eventually** and **what is the correct way to animate three elements with the same animation but some constant delay**. Thank you.

Comment: Using multiple shared values can cause this, can solved by either derived values or chaining completion callbacks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70314629/reanimated-v2-synchronised-shared-values (I can see that this is an older thread but comes up first in ggl)