# Reanimated v2 - Synchronised shared values

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

#### Question

I'm trying to create this animation using Reanimated v2:

[image]

This is the current implementation:

```js
const opacity1 = useSharedValue(0);
const opacity2 = useSharedValue(0);
const opacity3 = useSharedValue(0);
useEffect(() => {
  const duration = 600;
  const timingOptions = { duration: duration };
  const pulse = withTiming(1, timingOptions);
  const repeated = withRepeat(pulse, -1, true);
  opacity1.value = repeated;
  // *
  opacity2.value = withDelay(duration / 2, repeated);
  // *
  opacity3.value = withDelay(duration, repeated);
}, []);
```

The problem is that where I've marked the code with `// *` there seem to be some random delay (probably due to the JS execution) that cause the three dots to sometimes end up in sync (having the same opacity).

I presume the problem is that updating those 3 values is not atomic, so anything can happen in between those assignments.

What's the best way to solve this and have those 3 shared values with a deterministic delay between each other?

---

#### What have I tried?

- I tried using 1 `useSharedValue` and 2 `useDerivedValue`s but the math to get one to start at 0, one to start at 0.5, and one to start at 1 is non trivial (just adding 0.5 between each other and moduling it (%) to 1 doesn't account for the `withRepeat` going back after reaching 1)
- I tried using a `useSharedValue([0, 0, 0])` and then updating it with an atomic operation, but that doesn't seem to be supported

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found a solution, not sure if it's the best one but it currently works.

The idea is:

- have one shared value "progress" whose 0 -> 1 map to a complete animation cycle (e.g. 0 -> 1 -> 0)
- have 3 derived values that start at different moments and interpolate differently:

  - one 0 -> 0.5 -> 1 -> 0.5 -> 0
  - one 0.5 -> 1 -> 0.5 -> 0 -> 0.5
  - one 1 -> 0.5 -> 0 -> 0.5 -> 1

and here's the code:

```
const progress = useSharedValue(0);
useEffect(() => {
  const pulse = withTiming(1, { duration: 1200, easing: Easing.linear });
  progress.value = withRepeat(pulse, -1, false);
}, []);

const opacity1 = useDerivedValue(() =>
  interpolate(progress.value, [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1], [0, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 0])
);
const opacity2 = useDerivedValue(() =>
  interpolate(progress.value, [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1], [0.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5])
);
const opacity3 = useDerivedValue(() =>
  interpolate(progress.value, [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1], [1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1])
);
```